# Sencha Touch 2 docked tabpanel

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I have a panel with a tabbar and two tabs inside the tabbar. I don't know why, but it seems like I can't position the tabbar at the bottom. Whatever I try, the tabbar is always on top of the page.

The panel:

```
Ext.define( 'MyApp.view.Manager', {
    // properties
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    fullscreen: true,

    requires:
    [
        'Ext.TitleBar'
    ],
    config:
    {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        tabBar: true,
        items:
        [
            { xtype: 'addorderpanel' },
            { xtype: 'loginpanel' }
        ]
    }
});
```

The panel above is inside a container:

```
Ext.define( 'MyApp.view.Main', {
    // properties
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    config:
    {
        fullscreen: true
    },

    initialize: function ()
    {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        var manager = Ext.create( 'MyApp.view.Manager' );
        this.add(manager);
    }
});
```

If I add the first panel ('Manager') directly to the viewport, the tabbar is at the bottom and everything works as it should. Maybe it's bad practice to add a panel to a container, or am I wrong?

I hope someone can help me with this. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the layout propery to the config object in Main file. It should look like

```
Ext.define( 'MyApp.view.Main', {
    // properties
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        layout:'fit'
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        var manager = Ext.create( 'MyApp.view.Manager' );
        this.add(manager);
    }
});
```

Your tab panel is not getting any size, so the tabbar gets positioned to top.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why is it that you have to add some properties inside the 'config'-variable, and others not?

Comment: From what i've seen, all properties can go instide a config. But in a class definition u shouldn't nest configs. That means, dont put another item with a config object inside a config object.